# Getting 404 error to see a page newly generated with sails g page

Tags: routes, sails.js

I just generated a new page using sails generate page.

```
sails generate page user/foo-bar-1
```

I changed the route and linked to it from another page but I am getting a 404 error on my page.

```
'GET /user/top-level/foo-bar':    { action: 'user/foo-bar-1' },
```

Any ideas as to why I would be getting a 404 error for a newly generated page that I haven't touched other then changing the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in a recent version of sails generate, which messed up the names of automatically generated controllers. You may have to rename some of the files by hand. Don't forget to do all four files. (the controller, the page script, the view template, the less file) I believe the bug is fixed in the most recent version.